# hook_context_default_contexts() ?

Tags: importing-exporting, chaos-tool-suite, 7

I used Bulk Export to export all my Context definitions into my module in a function that implements hook_context_default_contexts().  However, my default context definitions do not appear if I delete the ones in the database.

Does this hook no longer work in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the piece I was missing:

```
/**
 * Implementation hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 *
 * Makes module compatible with context 3.
 */
function MY_MODULE_ctools_plugin_api($module, $api) {
  if ($module == 'context' && ($api == 'plugins' || $api == 'context')) {
    return array('version' => 3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work in Drupal 7, here you can see an example of a valid code from export created by [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * vw_product_search.context.inc
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_context_default_contexts().
 */
function vw_product_search_context_default_contexts() {
  $export = array();

  $context = new stdClass();
  $context->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default context disabled initially */
  $context->api_version = 3;
  $context->name = 'shop';
  $context->description = '';
  $context->tag = '';
  $context->conditions = array(
    'path' => array(
      'values' => array(
        'shop' => 'shop',
        'search' => 'search',
      ),
    ),
  );
  $context->reactions = array(
    'block' => array(
      'blocks' => array(
        'facetapi-WVeJBMTHZn1PCfPfrIPnjg1v8m19Gkqd' => array(
          'module' => 'facetapi',
          'delta' => 'WVeJBMTHZn1PCfPfrIPnjg1v8m19Gkqd',
          'region' => 'sidemenu_left',
          'weight' => '-10',
        ),
        'facetapi-H24ObDRB0Wq0KpRW1qalIgb7TvlKP7aj' => array(
          'module' => 'facetapi',
          'delta' => 'H24ObDRB0Wq0KpRW1qalIgb7TvlKP7aj',
          'region' => 'sidemenu_left',
          'weight' => '-9',
        ),
        'facetapi-GxgmQn2y5194O1hZ7qJIROIO63v5BKtG' => array(
          'module' => 'facetapi',
          'delta' => 'GxgmQn2y5194O1hZ7qJIROIO63v5BKtG',
          'region' => 'sidemenu_left',
          'weight' => '-8',
        ),
        'facetapi-zNmFD0ELaD0hTUYX9jyfnhkzHkz5GVvQ' => array(
          'module' => 'facetapi',
          'delta' => 'zNmFD0ELaD0hTUYX9jyfnhkzHkz5GVvQ',
          'region' => 'sidemenu_left',
          'weight' => '-7',
        ),
        'facetapi-kSPIS0vKCobobG533MMOWru8Q42SmByu' => array(
          'module' => 'facetapi',
          'delta' => 'kSPIS0vKCobobG533MMOWru8Q42SmByu',
          'region' => 'sidemenu_left',
          'weight' => '-6',
        ),
        'quicktabs-shop_facets' => array(
          'module' => 'quicktabs',
          'delta' => 'shop_facets',
          'region' => 'sidemenu_right',
          'weight' => '-8',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  $context->condition_mode = 0;
  $export['shop'] = $context;

  return $export;
}
```

Make sure that your module is enabled, that the hook implementation is correct and your caches flushed.