# How to import context module export -drupal 7

Tags: 7

I have created a Context using the Context module for use with a custom module.

Is it possible to export a context and then import it with my custom module? And if so, where does the data from the export need to go in my module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way1: Using Features module**

I would recommend you to use [features module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) to export your configurations like context, it will automatically pull the context configurations in code.

**Way2: Using custom module**

If for some reasons you want to do it in custom code then

- Use [context export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_export) to export your context. This module will let you the configuration code for context.
- Then create a plugin using hook_ctools_plugin_api and hook_context_default_contexts. Refernce link

  - [Sample Implementation for hook_ctools_plugin_api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106176/hook-context-default-contexts).

    - This will let Drupal aware of the context export plugin using ctools API.
  - [Sample Implementation for hook_context_default_contexts](http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites%21all%21modules%21flexslider%21flexslider_example%21flexslider_example.context.inc/function/flexslider_example_context_default_contexts/7.43).

    - Create file as _context.inc inside your
    - Add the implementation of hook_context_default_contexts on _context.inc file. As in [this](http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites%21all%21modules%21flexslider%21flexslider_example%21flexslider_example.context.inc/function/flexslider_example_context_default_contexts/7.43) example code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but after doing some more research, I realized I could do what I wanted to using hook_node_view.